# jQuery trigger function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to trigger the `enter-button-pressed` event for a text field using `jQuery`, my code is posted below but it does not trigger the `enter-button-pressed` event on the required field. Please tell what can be the issue?

**Code:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#txtEnglish").on('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#txtUrdu").val($("#txtEnglish").val());
        $("#txtUrdu").focus();
        $('#txtUrdu').trigger(jQuery.Event('keydown', {keyCode: 13}));
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried with `keypress` once like `$('#txtUrdu').trigger($.Event('keypress', {keyCode: 13}));` or `$('#txtUrdu').trigger($.Event('keypress', {which: 13}));`?

Comment: It works in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rm5yhtwu/2/) flawlessly. Only thing I have done is, adding a jQuery listener on `#txtUrdu` that `alert("Test " + event.keyCode);`, when the enter key is pressed while on `#txtEnglish`. It alerts `Test 13`, which is the expected!

Comment: Can you share your HTML

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your jQuery, the problem seems to be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add listener for your second input.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#txtEng').on('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        let text = $('#txtEng').val();
        $('#txtUrdu').val(text);
        $('#txtUrdu').focus();
        $('#txtUrdu').trigger('keydown', {
            keyCode: 13
        });
    }
});

 $('#txtUrdu').on('keydown', (e) => {
   if(e.isTrigger) {
    alert('here')
   } 
 })
})
```

[expample](https://jsfiddle.net/rjhgp9d6/11/)